# VSCode can't automatically detect bracket and quote

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

[image]

when I enter ", I expect the cursor jumps out of quotes, instead of something like this

[image]

It's really annoying, Is this because of some setup?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `editor.autoClosingOvertype` settings. It is `never` in your setup. It's `auto` by default.